# How can I refer to a trait's generic parameter in rust?

Tags: rust

for a trait with a type parameter I can reference it in the implementation like so:

```rust
impl Mul for Foo {
    type Output = Bar;
    fn mul(self, rhs: self) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

(`Self::Output` is what I'm referring to, or `<Self as Mul>::Output`)

is it possible to do the same for a trait's generic parameters? for example:

```rust
impl Into<Bar> for Foo {
    fn into(foo: Self) -> <Self as Into>::??? {
        unimplemented!()
    }

}
```

I'm at a loss for what to replace the question marks with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.  This usually isn't useful, anyway, and it definitely can't work the way you've attempted here because a single type can implement `Into<T>` multiple times with different generic parameters.  Assuming this worked with the same syntax as associated types, you'd have to spell out `<Self as Into<Bar>>::(something)` and then you're naming `Bar` right there anyway, but with a lot of extra stuff around it for no reason.

Just replace the entire return type with `Bar`.